# tools to manage kvm virtualization

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

what tools would you use to manage an environment of 40 physical servers running kvm virtualization ?

the requirements are:

provisioning via an api (can be something built in house)
metrics about virtual machines
migration of live virtual machines
snapshots for backups

thanks

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 4):

Have you taken a look at [**libvirt**](http://libvirt.org/) ?

**Edit**: Not quite sure what you mean by low-level since it has a GUI and all. But if you are looking for something web-based, how about [Eucalyptus](http://www.eucalyptus.com/)?

Comment: yes libvirt is the defacto for all other tools but is very low level

Comment: @silviud - edited my answer.

Comment: low level as is used into cli (nothing wrong with it from my point of view) but I was looking at something more web based - i know about eucalyptus as ubuntu it's using into their servers but i need something simple - like solusvm for example - lightweight and simple to install/administer.

Comment: libvirt has lots of command line tools and can be largely maintained through `virsh` and `virt-*` commands.

Comment: If libvirt is too low level, there is [oVirt](https://fedorahosted.org/ovirt/).

Answer (score 1):

Check out 'Cloud business' from http://www.witsbits.com. I think the current price is around 3 USD per core à month.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.convirture.com/ try this its open source product :)

Answer (score 0):

40 physical hosts is a serious environment. Have you taken a look at [RHEV](http://www.redhat.com/virtualization/rhev/server/)?